# tcp/ip Connection Errors

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mysql, postgresql

We have a web-server with 128GB main memory, 32 vCPUs on Ubuntu 16.04. It runs nginx, php-fpm, postgresql, mysql and beanstalkd applications.

The web-server gives some connection errors from different applications when it gets high throughput traffic. In normal times, everything is okay.

**Postgresql:**

```
 [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Mysql:**

```
 [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

**Beanstalkd:**

```
fwrite(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
```

Which settings of server (sysctl.conf maybe) affects these limits? How can I increase these limits to avoid errors?

Comment: First, you need to figure out what the problem is. You can't be sure you've solved the problem until you understand it.

Comment: I do not know what problem is. How can I find?

Comment: Do some load testing and see at how many concurrent connections your services fail. http://loader.io/ is good for basic testing

Comment: I am using newrelic to monitor my applications, so when it hits 20k rpm, it starts to fail. However, note that the system has 20 small machines and this is the master machine. Master machine basically gets results from small machines. This is only that I can collect...

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy, If you have a lot of connections into this server, you may want to start monitoring the number of connections the host server has.  If you exceed the limit the Linux kernel has built in for the number of connections allowed you may see connection failures at peak times. In the kernel log you may see lines such as

```
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
```

To see the limit on the number of connections:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max
```

To see the Number of current connections

```
wc -l /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```

If you see that the current connections are hitting the limit this would explain the problem.  You can try to increase the limit via the command below, but the kernel typically picks a number based on the hardware it is running on, and if the limit is raised above what the hardware can handle, that also can cause established connections to be broken when new connections are allocated.

To increase this limit (not preserved accross reboot)

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max=12000
```

Alternatively, add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf file to preserve this setting accross reboots:

```
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max=12000
```

I recommend the conntrack-tools provided by http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/

```
sudo apt-get install conntrack
```

This tool will let you see the connection list (-L), the counter (-C), and stats including dropped packets (-S)

Useful Link:  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ip_conntrack-table-ful-dropping-packet-error/